# Windows Phone simple data binding issue

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7, reflection

Here is my XAML code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="subTitle" Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

And my C# code:

```
PropertyInfo pi = ...;
subTitle.DataContext = pi;
```

The TextBlock displays simply nothing.

There is no DataContextChanged event but the TextBlock gets notified about the change because if I omit the path "Name" from the binding expression I get the ToString() representation of the DataContext. I can access no property of the bound object. There are no tools for debugging and I spent hours on this tiny but breaking issue.

Please help me solve this problem. Is it a bug or am I missing something? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that `PropertyInfo.Name` isn't a dependency property and/or it doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Create your own viewmodel object (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged) and use that for binding values to the view.

Comment: I tought when DataContext changes Silverlight invalidates bindings and finds the property specified in the Path clause by reflection. Every members of the object are set before the binding happens.

Comment: I have just created a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. It works as I expected, but I still do not know why is this required. Why can not happen a OneTime binding??? I hate Silverlight every day more (after WPF). Thank you for the answer.